# Table height with one row stretching row height

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have a table that has one row of tableheaders in it. The table has a height of 195px, and when it is rendered (js/jquery) the first row stretches the entire height of the table. How can I make it so the table row stays the default height?  I have tried using tr:first-child to set the height statically but it isn't working.

```
<table class="tabled">
<tr>
    <th>Header 1</th>
    <th>Header 2</th>
</tr>
</table>

<style>.tabled { height: 195px; } .tabled tr:first-child {20px; }</style>
```

This `<tr>` stretches the entirety of 195px when it is the only row in the table.

Comment: please add html and css so we can see what you are doing - and your js too if you are using it

Comment: why are you setting the height of the table to be 195px when you only want the row to be 20px? and you forgot to put height before the 20px

Comment: I fixed it myself by setting the table height to 'auto' and wrapping it in a div that was 195px.

Stack Overflow has honestly become such a useless and pathetic place more concerned with 'not doing people's work for them'.  It is truly sad.

Comment: All's well that ends well !

Answer (score 1):

You coud set the height via CSS by applying a class to the header row

```
<table class="tabled">
<tr class="header">
    <th>Header 1</th>
    <th>Header 2</th>
</tr>
</table>

<style>.tabled { height: 195px; } .header { height: 20px; }</style>
```

Comment: More rows are added with `$('.tabled').append('<tr><td>...</td></tr>');`

When the table is rendered, the first row stretches to 195px in height